# javascript: how to sort array of employee objects by age

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the employees object array by age and i'm getting the following output:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

However, the code works fine when i just replace the employees array with an array of numbers like:
var points=[2,10,7,8]

Can someone tell me on where i'm going wrong? Thank you.

The following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sortFunc(){

var employees=[]
 employees[0]={name:"George", age:32, retiredate:"March 12, 2014"}
 employees[1]={name:"Edward", age:17, retiredate:"June 2, 2023"}
 employees[2]={name:"Christine", age:58, retiredate:"December 20, 2036"}
 employees[3]={name:"Sarah", age:62, retiredate:"April 30, 2020"}

 employees.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.age-b.age
 // return a-b;
 })
 document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=employees;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="disp">Click the button below to sort.</div>
<button onclick="sortFunc()">Sort Now</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting works fine.
The way you're outputting it is incorrect.

Try to use a loop and than innerHTML to add it to the page.

```
var out="";
for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
  out+="<p>"+employees[i]['age']+", "+employees[i]['name']+"</p>\n";
}

document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=out;
```

Also you can define the object like that:

```
var employees=[
  {name:"George", age:32, retiredate:"March 12, 2014"},
  {name:"Edward", age:17, retiredate:"June 2, 2023"},
  {name:"Christine", age:58, retiredate:"December 20, 2036"},
  {name:"Sarah", age:62, retiredate:"April 30, 2020"}
]
```

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the sorting, it's because employees is an array of objects so, whether it's sorted or not, if you turn it into a string representation in order to add it to the document you are going to get

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

To display your data you'll need to be a bit more structured in the way you turn it into text.  For example:

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
   var employee = employees[i];
   html = html + employee.name + " " + employee.age + "<br/>";
}
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=employees;
```

Or you could look at using one of the many javascript templating libraries out there that make it easy to turn complex javascript structures into text / html.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

Your JavaScript however is missing all the semicolons. Plus you should use `push()` instead of direct assignment.

```
var employees = [];

employees.push( {name:"George", age:32, retiredate:"March 12, 2014"} );
employees.push( {name:"Edward", age:17, retiredate:"June 2, 2023"} );
employees.push( {name:"Christine", age:58, retiredate:"December 20, 2036"} );
employees.push( {name:"Sarah", age:62, retiredate:"April 30, 2020"} );

employees.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.age - b.age;
});
```

To output something readable, convert the data structure into a string first:

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function is indeed working. To view the output, try this:

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML='';
for(i=0; i<employees.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML+=employees[i].age+'<br>';
}
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is `document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=employees;` - you stuff the employees array in the HTML without manually converting it into valid HTML, so you get JavaScript's default textual representation of it, which happens to be `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`.

Try this instead:

```
function prepForHTML(emp) {
  var html='';
  for (var i=0;i<emp.length;i++) {
    for (var j in emp[i]) html+=j+"="+emp[i][j]+", ";
  }
  html+="<br>";
  return html;
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=prepForHTML(employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString()` method, the default will show you `[object Object]`.

***[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/ESNAX/)***

```
function Employee(name, age, retiredate) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.retiredate = retiredate;
}

Employee.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "Name:"+this.name+" Age:"+this.age+" Retiredate:"+this.retiredate;
};

var employees=[];
employees.push(new Employee("George", 32, "March 12, 2014"));
employees.push(new Employee("Edward", 17, "June 2, 2023"));
employees.push(new Employee("Christine", 58, "December 20, 2036"));
employees.push(new Employee("Sarah", 62, "April 30, 2020"));

employees.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.age-b.age;
});

document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=employees;
```